# How to Change Firestore Document Field Name After Creation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's assume we have a user document like this:

```
- user # Document
    - naem # Field
```

Unfortunately, there was a mistake in naming the field of this document. Instead of "naem", it should have been "name".

This document has already been created for a large number of users, but we want to modify the field names for all users.

In such a case, what methods are available to efficiently change the field name?